# While I am trying to call my method, which is created in the main method, I am getting errors

Tags: java

```
public class MyClass
{
    public  static short subtractNumbers (short a, byte b, float k )
    {
        int x=(short)a;
        int y=(short)b;
        int z=(short)k;
        return (short)(x+y-z);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(subtractNumbers(127,127,0.0f));
    }    
}
```

When I compile and run the program, I am getting errors, as:

```
error: method subtractNumbers in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;

System.out.println(subtractNumbers(127,127,0.0f));

required: short,byte,float

found: int,int,float

reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to short by method invocation conversion
```

Why are the code causing the errors? I am wondering.

Thanks in advance for the help it would be appreciated.

Comment: You're passing in 2 full integers to the `subtractNumbers` method, when it actually accepts a short, a byte and a float.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states you are passing 2 int numbers instead of a short and a byte. Try:

```
System.out.println(subtractNumbers((short) 127, (byte) 127, 0.0f));
```

Or change your method to:

```
public static short subtractNumbers(int a, int b, float k) {
    return (short) (a + b - (int) k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that in Java an integer literal is an `int` unless:

1. you specify it as a `long` e.g. `128L` (There is no specifier for `short` or `byte` unfortunately)
2. assign it to another integer type e.g. `short s = 1;`
3. you cast it explicitly e.g. `(short) 4`
4. you have a *Widening primitive conversion* e.g. pass an `int` to a method expecting a `long`

A conversion from `int` to `short` or `byte` is called a *Narrowing primitive conversion* and it may fail generally, if the `int` is too large to fit in a `short`.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating variables before calling the subtractNumbers method. That way, you can set the type you want and it won't complain about the types not being the same.